# Grails web application FREE testing tool to test sql injection,XSS vulnerabilities

Tags: java, grails

Can anyone help me in finding some good free testing tool to test SQL Injection and XSS vulnerabilities. I found Pros and sql inject me(firefox add-on) , but these are not very helpful.

Thanks
Vipin Mittal

Answer (score 0):

[Nessus](http://www.tenable.com/products/nessus) has SQL injection and XSS testing. And yes, there is a free version, too.